# How to display response from custom phantomjs scripts

Tags: laravel, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

I can't seem to be able to display a response from my custom .proc file. I'm running php-phantomjs on laravel 5.6 on ubuntu. I've got a URL endpoint I'm using to invoke the custom file as follows:

```php
public function getLinks()
{
    $location = base_path('phantom-scripts');


    $serviceContainer = ServiceContainer::getInstance();

    $procedureLoader = $serviceContainer->get('procedure_loader_factory')
        ->createProcedureLoader($location);

    $client = Client::getInstance();
    $client->getEngine()->setPath(\Config::get('phantomPath'));
    $client->setProcedure('my_procedure');
    $client->getProcedureLoader()->addLoader($procedureLoader);

    $request  = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest();
    $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

    $client->send($request, $response);
    dd($response->getContent());
  }
```

Here's the .proc file

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

console.log("loading...");



var url = 'http://www.example.com';

page.open(url, function (status) {

    if (status === "success") {

        var contentNeeded = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.querySelector("h1").outerHTML;
        });


        console.log(contentNeeded);

    }


});


phantom.exit();
```

I'd like to display the 'contentNeeded' on my browser.

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS exits too early in your script.

`page.open` calls are asynchronous (who knows how much time opening that url will take), so `phantom.exit()` runs right after the browser's only started opening that url. Instead exit PhantomJS after getting the info, in callback:

```
if (status === "success") {

    var contentNeeded = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector("h1").outerHTML;
    });

    console.log(contentNeeded);
    phantom.exit();
}
```

Comment: Tried it and still getting null as the result of the dd(). Is console.log the right way to print out / return content from the .proc file?

Comment: Maybe not, I'm not very familiar with Laravel or Symphony — just pointed out a mistake that definitely would ruin your script if you did things right PHP-wise.

Comment: dd() - dump and die - is simply a function that either does print_r for arrays or echo for variables then exits the php script. That said, I've moved away from the php-phantomjs wrapper and instead, I'll run exec() on the phantom script directly since I've found no recourse. Thanks for the input.